# Swift: Image size is increasing after writing that image to folder even after compressing the image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nsfilemanager

I'm saving an image picked from Photos in a Document folder.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }
    selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0).fileSize() //Printing size as 4284217 bytes|4.3 MB
    if let imageData = selectedImage.jpeg(.lowest) {
        imageData.fileSize() //Printing size as 4284217 bytes|4.3 MB
        let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)?.fixOrientation()
        saveImageInDocuments(compressedImage!)
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

After selecting the image and compressing to minimum size, I have printed the size of Image. Next step is to save Image to Documents Folder.

```
func saveImageInDocuments(_ image: UIImage) {
    let imageName = String(Date().toMillis())
    let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(CUST_APP_DOC)/\(imageName).png")
    print(fileURL.path)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            try image.pngData()!.write(to: fileURL)                
            print("Saved filename: \(imageName).png size: \(calculateFileSize(path: String(describing: fileURL)).0)")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
        print("Image Not Added")
    }
}
```

Methods used to get size of the image and calculate the size of Image saved at path

```
 func calculateFileSize(path: String) -> (String, Double) {
    let absolutePath = path.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")
    let fileAttributes = try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: absolutePath)
    let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as! NSNumber
    let fileSize = fileSizeNumber.int64Value
    var sizeMB = Double(fileSize / 1024)
    sizeMB = Double(sizeMB / 1024)
    print(String(format: "%.2f", sizeMB) + " MB")
    return (String(format: "%.2f", sizeMB) + " MB", sizeMB)
}

extension Data {
    func fileSize() {
        let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
        bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB] // optional: restricts the units to MB only
        bcf.countStyle = .file
        let string = bcf.string(fromByteCount: Int64(self.count))
        print("Printing size as \(self.count) bytes|\(string) MB")
    }
}
```

The issue is that after selecting the image the image file size is 4.3 MB but while after saving the image in folder. The size of image is coming "**Saved filename: 1546593850872.png size: 29.86 MB**"

Why is this happening? If anyone can help to explain this, I will be thankful to the person.

Comment: You have to compress image size and then store in document directory, this what you want to do?

Comment: There is information missing here, After checking the compressed data size you are calling `.fixOrientation()`, what does this do? what is `CreateUploadingPdf()`??

Comment: @Scriptable  `.fixOrientation()` is for changing orientation of the image. In my case image orientation was changing in some cases. `CreateUploadingPdf()` I have removed that, although that was a class where `calculateFileSize()` was defined.

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav Yes that what I'm doing but on writing that image to directory . Image size is getting increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for this whole day, I found the answer to this scenario.

In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I was compressing the image to JPEG where the image size was getting reduced. Then while writing the image to directory `saveImageInDocuments`, I was converting the JPEG image again to PNG using this line of code.

`try image.pngData()!.write(to: fileURL)`

Converting the image to PNG was increasing its size.

For solution I have modified this method:

```
func saveImageInDocuments(_ imageData: Data) {
    let imageName = String(Date().toMillis())
    let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(CUST_APP_DOC)/\(imageName).png")
    print(fileURL.path)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            try imageData.write(to: fileURL)                
         } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
        print("Image Not Added")
    }
}
```

Directly saved the compressed JPEG image.